# Show that operator is bounded for all x

Tags: functional-analysis

I don't understand how to show boundedness of an operator in order for it to compute it's norm.

Operator $A: X \rightarrow Y$, where $X = l_1,\; Y = l_2$ (Perhaps $ X \in l_1, \; Y \in l_2 $ would be correct ?)

I understand that operator is bounded if $\;\exists M>0\;, \forall x \in X : \quad||Ax|| \leq M||x||$

Isn't $M$ expressed as: $||A|| = \sup_{||x||\leq1}||Ax||$ ? If that is so, why should we first find $M$ and then compute $||A||$ ?

I'm confused about this.

For a side note, X and Y are infinite sequences.

$X = (x_1,x_2,x_3,...) \; Y= (y_1,y_2,y_3,...) \; \text{and } y_n = x_n - x_{n-1},\; y_1 = x_1$

Comment: "Isn't the question asking...": _What_ question?

Comment: You are messing up spaces and their elements; either X is the $l^1$ space or the element $(x_1,x_2,...)$. What have you tried? Yes, compute the norms and try to find a bound on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding $sup_{||x||=1} ||Ax||$ would prove the boundedness of A.
Proving the continuity of A would also suffice.

I think that if you set $x_0 = 0$ the following inequalities give a straight forward proof that $2$ is an upper bound of the given operator A for any element $x$ of $\ell^1$:

$||Ax||_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty(Ax)_n^2} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_{n+1} - x_n|^2} \le \sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_{n+1} - x_n| \le \sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_n| + \sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_{n-1}| \le 2 \sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_n|$

Now you know that the norm of the operator $A$ is well defined by $||A|| = sup_{x\not=0}\frac{||Tx||}{||x||}=sup_{||x||=1}||Tx||$ and that $||A|| \le 2$. To find the value of $||A||$ it is enough to show that $||A|| \ge 2$.
Consider the sequence $(1,0,0,...)$.

$||(1,0,0,...)||_1=1$

$A(1,0,0,...) = (1,1,0,0,...)$

$||A(1,0,0,...)||_2 = ||(1,1,0,0,...)||_2 = \sqrt{1^2+1^2}=2$

so since there is a countable sequence $x_0 = (1,0,0,...)$ of $\ell^1$ norm $1$ such that $||Ax_0||_2=2$ it must hold that $||A|| \ge 2$. Then $||A||=2$.